# Does seazone 12 touch Gibraltar in Axies and Allies

Tags: axis-and-allies

Does Gibraltar touch seazone 12 in Axis and Allies spring 1942?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Gibraltar]

The red line is the separation line between sea zone 12 and 13.

Krieghund, the developer and Q&A author at [axisandallies.org](https://www.axisandallies.org/forums/topic/13929/gibraltar-and-sz12?_=1673404430957), clarified Gibraltar connects to sea zone 13.

> Q: Is Gibraltar connencted to SZ12 or SZ13?
> A: 13

They also answered a similar question on [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1743055/article/25314500#25314500).

> Q: Does a ship or plane have to enter the Med before landing on the Rock?
> A: Sea zone 12 doesn't connect to Gibraltar